# How do I create a container which sits directly in the middle of the page and zooms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a small little personal project which is just a simple page which displays the total amount of COVID-19 cases. I am quite new to HTML and CSS and was just wondering what the best way is to put these items in a container and directly centre them both horizontally and vertically. I have looked around quite a bit and have been unable to find what I am looking for. This is the current code that I am using

```
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="display"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('display').textContent = data.results[0].total_cases.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  });
</script>
```

I know that I am going to want to put the div container tags around the start and end of the script command. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

enjoy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style=" 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;">
    <div id="display"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('display').textContent = data.results[0].total_cases.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

try this code now [EDIT]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style=" 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column;">
    <div>
    Total Confirmed
    </div>
    <div id="display"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('display').textContent = data.results[0].total_cases.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would be the code required to make it so that way I could have a small bit of text above the number received from the API while still keeping them both aligned? I tried padding and padding-top but I haven't found a solution; would it be something to do with containers?

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean show me what you want

Comment: That javascript code outputs the current amount of confirmed COVID cases received from the API link. I wanted to put some text above that number which says something along the lines of "Total Confirmed Cases", I have managed to do it by changing the height percentage however it doesn't scale with the number when I zoom in and out.

Comment: what does zoom in zoom out means ? browser zomming ?

Comment: ok i got it what you want. can you show me the current code you are using. moreover this link says = `Uploads are disabled.
File uploads require push access to this repository.`

Comment: Sorry my bad I sent the link before uploading.
https://github.com/GreenishUwU/covid-tracker-personal-site

I copied the same CSS that you used for the counter for the text but just changed the height percentage so it wouldn't be on top of the number/counter however when I zoom they both end up getting big and overlapping eachother. I am assuming that I have to put them together in the same container or something. Thanks so much for the help so far :)

Comment: i can't see any `Total Confirmed` in the code. leme give you my code with `Total Confirmed`. try running it

Comment: On the first line of body I have it in the <p2> tags which are then defined in the style.css file to have the same attributes as the code that you gave me except  for more stuff for the text and a different height.
Would you have discord? I think it may be more convenient for us to chat there.

Comment: try the edited code brother